# Matplotlib: How to plot points on my graph instead of painting them on a button?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

**Edit**: `ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)` works fine, IDK how I went past this. However, pressing the button is still paint dots and I'm wondering if filtering coordinates is good practice to solve this.

Here is my minimal code to plot some points on axis. Unfortunately, with the button code `plt.scatter()` stops working properly (dots start to appear on top of the button).Any advice for me?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])


def onclick(event):
    plt.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
    fig.canvas.draw()


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)


def do(event):
    print(1)


bprev = Button(plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075]), 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(do)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Upvoted for the great (although unintentional) effect. Make it `ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)`, though.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you!!! IDK how I went past this... Then I think I will be filtering the clicks by coordinates to avoid painting if the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the first problem, as Mr T. pointed out, you can use `ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)` to plot on the main axes, not on the button.

To solve the problem of points being plotted when the button is clicked, you can use the `event.inaxes` property, which tells you the Axes instance of the mouse click. So, if `event.inaxes` is the same as `ax`, draw the point; if not, then it is in the button, so do nothing.

In your function, it would look like this:

```
def onclick(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        fig.canvas.draw()
```